# Symfony: Pagination + Sorting?

Tags: php, symfony1

The pagination in Symfony is pretty straightforward and pretty good. However I'm looking for the best direction to go for adding in Sorting to the table.

My thoughts are that the sorting column, direction and current page number are defined in the uri, like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/backend_dev.php/articles/author/asc/3/
```

And then on each page, Symfony uses the uri to determine the current sorting column, direction and page and then manipulates all the pagination links to take those things into account so that when you click on a link to change pages or sort by a different column it takes you to the proper place.

Does anyone have any other directions I could go with this? I know about the simplicity of jQuery's tablesorter plugin but it sucks when there are 1000+ records because you have to load them all at once to make that plugin work.

Comment: If you use doctrine, this may interest you : http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/zh/utilities:pagination

Comment: Thanks, the pagination is taken care of, but that page doesn't offer any suggestions on sorting.

Comment: You can modify the Doctrine_Query depending on the parameters you'll get from your route , which must be like `/articles/:sorting_column/:sorting_direction/:limit`

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, I'm just asking if there are any alternative/better directions to go.

Answer (score 0):

The generator admin has an interesting approach. It gets the sorting from URI as well like below.

```
/backend_dev.php/pedidos?sort=status&sort_direction=asc
```

In order not to carry those get parameters throughout the links (it's a pain to do that), it stores in the user session. Let's see an example. In the action you'll have

```
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    // sorting
    if ($request->getParameter('sort') && $this->isValidSortColumn($request->getParameter('sort')))
    {
      $this->setSort(array($request->getParameter('sort'), $request->getParameter('sort_type')));
    }

    // pager
    if ($request->getParameter('page'))
    {
      $this->setPage($request->getParameter('page'));
    }

    $this->pager = $this->getPager();
    $this->sort = $this->getSort();
  }    

//// more code


  protected function setPage($page)
  {
    $this->getUser()->setAttribute('ef3Pedido.page', $page, 'admin_module');
  }

  protected function getPage()
  {
    return $this->getUser()->getAttribute('ef3Pedido.page', 1, 'admin_module');
  }

  protected function getSort()
  {
    if (null !== $sort = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('ef3Pedido.sort', null, 'admin_module'))
    {
      return $sort;
    }

    $this->setSort($this->configuration->getDefaultSort());

    return $this->getUser()->getAttribute('ef3Pedido.sort', null, 'admin_module');
  }

  protected function setSort(array $sort)
  {
    if (null !== $sort[0] && null === $sort[1])
    {
      $sort[1] = 'asc';
    }

    $this->getUser()->setAttribute('ef3Pedido.sort', $sort, 'admin_module');
  }

  protected function isValidSortColumn($column)
  {
    return Doctrine::getTable('Pedido')->hasColumn($column);
  }
```

It's a nice approach for both, the end user and the developer.

Comment: It sounds like an interesting approach, but how do you accomplish this without carrying the get parameters through all the links? When you visit a page, how are the get parameters going to be in the URI if they aren't added to the links?

Comment: Looking at your code, it looks like it gets the parameter from the sort & direction parameters from the URI and then it sets them in the session. But then what do you do with those session values? How do they help you not have to carry all the parameters into the links?

Comment: Well, before setting up the query for the pager, use the functions getPage() and getSort() to get from the session the stored values. Then use set them in the pager.

Comment: @P.R.Ribeiro I am stuck in sorting. I am implementing the same code But   I am getting an error in the getPager() function. I have implemented is as :                                                                    protected function getPager() {
        $pager = $this->configuration->getPager('BirthLegalInfo');
        $pager->setQuery($this->buildQuery());
        $pager->setPage($this->getPage());
        $pager->init();
        return $pager;
    }  The error which I am getting is Fatal error: Call to a member function getPager() on a non-object. BirthLegalInfo is the the class in model